# Issues using cwrsync on windows

Tags: windows, rsync

I am trying to use `cwrsync` on a windows machine to copy logfiles from a remote Linux host to my local PC through SSH. When I run the command below, I get an error in my CMD prompt that fails to resolve the hostname because ssh is trying to resolve DNS to the full file path for the source files.

```
rsync -avzhe "ssh user@192.168.0.230:/var/www/logs/AccessLog*" "C:\TESTLOGS\"
```

If I use

```
rsync -avzhe "ssh user@192.168.0.230" "C:\TESTLOGS\"
```

the command executes properly and I see the TCP connection reach out to the destination IP in wireshark. But I need a reliable way to specify the path of the source file.

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\rsync>rysnctest.cmd
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.168.0.230:/var/www/logs/accesslog*: Name or service not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.2]

C:\Users\admin\Desktop\rsync>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or how to fix this?

Comment: Try `rsync -avzhe "ssh -p 22" user@192.168.0.230:/var/www/logs/AccessLog* C:\TESTLOGS\`

Comment: No luck, the program kicks back an error that both the source and destination cannot both be remote when i use that.  I did at least get it to attempt the SSH connection using 'rsync -avzhe "ssh user@192.168.0.230 /var/www/logs/AccessLog*" "C:\TESTLOGS\"' but then I had to add another SSH option, I think -o, to specify the key exchange algorithm and once I actually got it to connect to the server, I then ran into permission issues with trying to copy the files, even though the login I used for rsync is the one that I typically use to open an SSH/WinSCP session.